# Help, no clue how to make this Makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have read several tutorials but I still do not have any clue :-) I have a c File "liboratidy.c" this file includes some oder libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <tidy.h>
#include <buffio.h>
#include <oci.h>
#include <ociextp.h>
```

The needed files are located in /user/lib/libtidy.so and header files in /usr/include/tidy/ and /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/rdbms/public/

I try to compile my code as shared library but every way I invoke my gcc compiler I will get a "xy.h file not found" error. But the files are existing. I have never done something with c,c++ ... how do I make a Makefile for compiling this source?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-I` options should point to the directories (e.g. `-I /usr/include/tidy`) that contain the header files you need to compile against. The `-L` options should point to the directories (e.g. `-L /usr/lib/opracle/.....`) that contain the libraries you need to build against. The `-l` options should contain the shortened name (e.g. `libfoo.so` -> `-lfoo`) of the libraries you want to build against.

Comment: ahaa ... I never did the -I option but tried several ways with -L and -l. Finally this one works:$ gcc -I/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/rdbms/public/ -I/usr/include/tidy/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/ -ltidy -shared -o test.so
thank you very much!